# In the following multithreaded applet only the first thread is getting executed?

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

The program is sending packets from sender to receiver and back to sender from receiver. It is using thread for each packet but only first packet is traversing the route.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class CongestionControl extends Applet {
   ArrayList<Packets> packetList = new ArrayList();
   static int width, height;
   int packetCount;
   static int sourceLocationX;
   private Label ls = new Label("Sender");
   private Label lr = new Label("Reciever");
   int sourceLocationY;
   int SWS;
   int packetWidth;
   int packetHeight;
   static int destLocationX;
   Random random = new Random();
   int RTT;

   public CongestionControl() {
      sourceLocationX = 100;
      sourceLocationY = 200;
      destLocationX = 400;
      RTT = 5;
      SWS = 4;
      packetWidth = 10;
      packetHeight = 10;
      packetCount = 10;
   }

   public void init() {
      width = getSize().width;
      height = getSize().height;
      setLayout(null);
      for (int i = 0; i < packetCount; i++) {
         packetList.add(new Packets(sourceLocationX, sourceLocationY, Math
               .round(((2 * (-sourceLocationX + destLocationX)) / RTT) + 2)));
         // adding 2 purposely
      }
      add(ls);
      ls.setBounds(100, 240, 140, 30);
      add(lr);
      lr.setBounds(destLocationX + 20, 240, 140, 30);
   }

   private class MovingRunnable implements Runnable {
      private final Packets p;

      private MovingRunnable(Packets p) {
         this.p = p;
      }

      public void run() {
         for (;;) {
            p.move();
            repaint();
            try {
               Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public void start() {
      for (Packets packet : packetList) {
         Thread t;
         t = new Thread(new MovingRunnable(packet));
         try {
            Thread.sleep(RTT / SWS); // packet generation interval
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         t.start();
         System.out.println("New thread generated");
      }
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      super.paint(g);
      for (Packets Packet : packetList) {
         g.drawRect(Packet.x, Packet.y, packetHeight, packetWidth);
         g.drawLine(sourceLocationX, sourceLocationY + packetHeight,
               destLocationX, sourceLocationY + packetHeight);
      }
   }

   public class Packets {
      int x;
      int y;
      int deltaX;
      int deltaY;

      public Packets(int startx, int starty, int deltax) {
         this.x = startx;
         this.y = starty;
         this.deltaX = deltax / 5;
      }

      public void move() {
         x += deltaX;
         if (x >= CongestionControl.destLocationX - packetWidth) {
            x = x - deltaX;
            deltaX = -deltaX;
            y += (packetHeight + 10);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Why only first thread is running?

Comment: Your code as formatted is very difficult to read. Please consider editing your post and fixing your indentation style so that it is uniform and consistent. I usually avoid using tabs for indenting (the site's software often doesn't play well with tabs) and indent each code block 4 spaces and only 4 spaces.

Comment: Edit: I've formatted your code for you this time, but in the future, please put in this effort yourself. It's not asking much of you, and will make helping you much easier.